# Will Lucene ALWAYS return ALL the documents that match my query same way as the SQL select query does?

Tags: lucene, nosql

I'm using Lucene to index the values that I'm storing in an object database. I'm storing a reference (UUID) to the object along with the field names and their corresponding values (Lucene Fields) in the Lucene Document.

My question is will Lucene ALWAYS return ALL the documents that match my query?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer depends on which analyzer(s) you have used for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on analyzer which you are using and also you **can limit the no of result** while searching.

for better searching you also can use [Apache's open source search platform - Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).